# Steps to Write php script for cron job to execute a function

Tags: php, mysql, cron

I need to implement a cron job which run everyday at 8:00 AM.I don't have any idea what needs to be done.
the cron should run the a function greet() on this file.

```
<?php
    class Person {
     public $age=0;
     public  $isalive=false;
     public $name;
     public $msg;
     public $isAlive=true;
     public $firstname;
     public $lastname;

     public function __construct($fname,$lname,$age){
        $this->firstname=$fname;
        $this->lastname=$lname;
        $this->age=$age;
        $this->name=$fname." ".$lname;
        //$this->isAlive=$isAlive;
     }

         public function greet(){
             echo "$this->name says $this->msg my age is $this->age <br> am I alive:$this->isAlive";
         }
    }
     $teacher = new Person('boring','12345',12345);
     $student = new Person('Swapnil','Shende',24);
     echo $student->age;

     ?>
```

Comment: "I need to implement a cron job which run everyday at 8:00 AM.I don't have any idea what needs to be done." — Try reading the manual for cron.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cron+manual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the cron tab and open it like this

```
crontab -e
```

then add this line

```
* 8 * * *   filename.php
```

where filename.php is your file name

Also edit your file.php to call those function like this at the end

```
 $teacher = new Person('boring','12345',12345);
 $student = new Person('Swapnil','Shende',24);
 $student->greet();
 $teacher->greet();
```

Comment: but i neeed to write php script that will schedule the cron to run the function greet() from this file.

Comment: that is the functionality of cron job it will schedule it for you just edit your file.php to call the function at the end like this $student->greet(); and $teacher->greet();

Comment: Thanks this gives a better idea.

Comment: For this to work, you'll need a hashbang at the start of your file (`#!/usr/bin/php`), otherwise the system won't know how to run the PHP file. Or, you can just add this in your cron line directly (`/usr/bin/php /path/to/script.php`).

Answer (score 0):

```
crontab -e
* 8 * * *  file.php
```

where file.php contain:

```
<?php
include ('Person.class.php');
$teacher = new Person('boring','12345',12345);
$student = new Person('Swapnil','Shende',24);
$teacher->greet();
$student->greet();
?>
```

and delete this part from your class

```
$teacher = new Person('boring','12345',12345);
$student = new Person('Swapnil','Shende',24);
echo $student->age;
```